# Who was 'us' in the Garden of Eden?

Tags: genesis

When the Lord God banishes Adam and Eve from the Garden of Eden, the Lord says,

> 'The man has now become like one of **us**, knowing good and evil.'  - Genesis 3:22 NIV

When God said 'us', who did he mean?

Comment: An answer for this question can probably be found in the answer for [Genesis 1.26](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/interpretation-of-genesis-126).